# Showing if someone is reading a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I want to show the list of people who are reading a post.
Before attempting to implement the function, I wanted to ask for some advice. I would start by checking users who invoke the `show` action in the `PostsController`; every time a person views a post, he will be recorded onto  the list of people who are reading the post. However, I am not sure how to **remove** the person from the list when he **navigates away** from reading the post. Is there a way to use `cookies` or `sessions` to notice if the user navigates away from a certain page? A little bit of help would help me get started right away!

I appreciate any advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more accurate

in routes.rb

```
post "/posts/:id/being_read" => "posts#being_read", :defaults => { :format => "json"}
```

in controller

```
PostsController < ApplicationController
  def being_read
    current_user && @post.being_read_by current_user
    head :ok
  end
end
```

on show page

```
function beingRead(){
  $.post("/posts/<%=@post.id%>/being_read", function(data) {
    setTimeout(beingRead,10000);
  });
}
```

in post.rb

```
def being_read_by user=nil
  # making use of rails low level cache

  readers_ids = Rails.cache.fetch("Post #{id} being read", :expires_in => 5.minutes) || []

  readers_ids = Rails.cache.fetch("Post #{id} being read", :expires_in => 5.minutes) (readers_ids << user.id) if user

  readers_ids
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Amol! I didn't expect to get the actual code like this. I really appreciate it but I will try to implement by myself to understand the logic better :)

Comment: If you have time, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845446/railsautomatically-remove-a-record-after-a-few-minutes

Comment: It depends, if you need to maintain history further(db) or just for time being(cache)

Answer (score 2):

Usually, a system of timeout is used.

Rather than store a boolean "is reading post", we can store the date on which the user has read the post.

No, you can easily set a timeout (for example 5 minutes) to know who are reading the post. This is an approximation, but this is almost realistic.

Advantages :

- you can delete the finished dates when you want (with a cron, each day, or something else), with a single query rather than one a each view.
- you resolve the problem of the user who close its browser (when no next page is open)

Comment: Thanks for this! With just a bit more help, I think I'd be able to implement this. I think I will create a model called `Reader` and set `post has_many readers` but I'm concerned if this is inefficient?

Comment: So every time a user reaches a post, I would do 
`post.readers.create(user: current_user)`, and this record should be expired after 5 minutes automatically. Is that possible?

Comment: If you have time, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845446/railsautomatically-remove-a-record-after-a-few-minutes