# Automatically remove a record after a few minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timeout

I am going to use `timeout` as advised in my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830212/showing-if-someone-is-reading-a-post/15830340#15830340). So if a person views a post, he will be recorded into the list of people who are viewing the same post, and this record will be expired after a certain period of time (e.g. 5 minutes).

Someone advised me to use `cache` to achieve this, but I think I will try to do it with Rails associations like follows.

`post has_many readers`

And in the `PostsController#Show`

`@post.readers.create(user: current_user)` **and I need to make this record to be expired after 5 minutes, so that the current_user will be removed from post.readers automatically.**

Is this the right approach? Also, how do I set the `Reader` model so that any record will be deleted after 5 minutes it is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just retrieve the latest readers when you do the query:

```
post.readers.where('created_at >= ?', 5.minutes.ago)
```

Then you can have a background job to do the cleanup.

Comment: But how can I determine when I should run the "cleanup" job to eliminate the `readers`?

Comment: The job would run periodically (for example every 24 hours) and would delete all the records in the `readers` table that where created before 5 minutes ago.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the easiest way to deal with this problem. But I'm still a little bit unsure how I can periodically run a certain job in my application without anyone having to invoke the action.

Comment: @MaximusS There are several tools for that. Check out [this RailsCast to find out about Cron](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby). There are also more advanced solutions like [Resque](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) or [Sidekiq](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq).

Comment: Thanks very much. Could you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846517/railsambiguous-table-reference if you have some time?