# Ambiguous table reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, activerecord-relation

This problem seems fairly simple, but I've never encountered one like this.

Here are the settings:

```
Post has_many :reader_links
Post has_many :readers, :through => :reader_links
```

I need to find out if there are readers reading a post.

`@post.reader_links.where('created_at >= ?', 45.minutes.ago).any?`

Works great.

`@post.readers.where('created_at >= ?', 45.minutes.ago),any?`

throws an *ambiguous table column* error because it's confused whether the `created_at` column means that of **reader** object or **reader_link** object. This happens because the class of a reader is actually **User.** How do I query **readers who were created by reader_links 45 minutes ago?**

I'm looking for something like..

`@post.readers.where('reader_link.created_at >= ?', 45.minutes.ago)`

Comment: please add sample data and expected output to your question. guessing gets a bit hard at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, you just need to specify which `created_at` column you're talking about:

```
@post.readers.where('reader_links.created_at >= ?', 45.minutes.ago).any?
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you again. All I needed was to make `reader_link` to `reader_links` in the original code.

Answer (score 1):

You coul merge the scopes to get rid of ambigious errors, so each scope has it's own visibility range.

using `meta_where`:

```
Post.scoped & (ReaderLink.scoped & User.where(:created_at.gt => 45.minutes.ago))
```

without `meta_where`:

```
Post.scoped.merge(ReaderLink.scoped.merge(User.where('created_at >= ?', 45.minutes.ago))
```

This will result in arrays of `Post` objects containing the reader_links and readers data for all readers younger than 45 minutes. Please try it in the rails console.

Edit: for a single post

```
post_with_fresh_users = Post.where('id = ?', some_id).merge(ReaderLink.scoped.merge(User.where('created_at >= ?', 45.minutes.ago))
```

Edit: all fresh readers of a post (different order)

```
fresh_readers_for_post = User.where('created_at >= ?', 45.minutes.ago).merge(ReaderLink.scoped.merge(Post.where('id = ?', @post.id))
```

How it works:

http://benhoskin.gs/2012/07/04/arel-merge-a-hidden-gem

Comment: thanks for your input. But I am still lost how to query the readers who were added to the reader_link table, which is associated with a post, within 45 minutes.

Comment: Is there a way to query with an object instead of a model? e.g. @post.scoped .. rather than Post.scoped .. I am unsure how to apply your code to a single post.

Comment: Added that case. the word `scoped` basically just converts the basic Model to an ActiveRecord::Relation without any narrowing (like `WHERE 1`). So of course you can change scoped for any narrowing, you would like, as the where in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But still, I want to call the `readers` but the code calls the `essays` that have readers.

Comment: my code produces the posts, where the readers where created wihtin the last 45 minutes? Do you want the readers that were created 45 minutes ago associated with a Post or just associated with reader_links?

Comment: The readers. For anyone viewing the post, I want to show other people who are looking at the same post. `@readers = something.`

Comment: Also, `Reader` is just a name defined in the `ReaderLink` table that references `User` class.